# File with extension .prd downloaded as HTML file

Tags: html, anchor, gatsby

I have a problem with downloading .prd extension files. The Chrome and Safari on mobile device is downloading it as html, only safari on desktop keeps .prd format. Any suggestions with this problem ?

```
<a href="./platform-prototype-sample.prd" download="platform-prototype-sample.prd">
   <p>Download Mobile Prototype</p>
</a>
```

Comment: Does it rename extension? What headers you get when requesting file?

Comment: I cannot see any requests in network when I download this file.

Comment: Do this request via Postman

Comment: content-encoding →gzip.    content-type →text/html; charset=UTF-8

Comment: So try changing `Content-Type`